# How does Python3 multiprocessing Process pass variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm pretty new to Python but trying to learn how to use multi-processing. I have a method to time method execution, but for some reason the list object isn't being changed.

See code below, what am I missing?

```
def timeMethod(methodToTime, methodVar, methodVar2):
     start = datetime.now()
     if methodVar2 == None and methodVar == None:
          methodToTime()
     elif methodVar2 == None:
          methodToTime(methodVar)
     else:
          methodToTime(methodVar, methodVar2)

     end = datetime.now()
     time_elapsed = end - start
     print("Seconds Elapsed = ", time_elapsed)

def indirectList(aList):
     appendToList(aList)

def appendToList(aList):
     aList.append(1)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
     import sys
     primeList = []
     print("primeList before execution: " + str(primeList))
     p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=timeMethod, args=(indirectList, primeList, None)) 
     p3.start()
     p3.join()
     print("primeList after execution: " + str(primeList))
     print("Done!")
```

Console Output:

```
primeList before execution: []
Seconds Elapsed =  0:00:00
primeList after execution: []
Done!
```

Comment: `multiprocessing` **does not share state**. It creates *multiple python processes*.

Comment: That is not true, see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 2):

Processes don't share the same memory. Python multiprocessing serializes (pickles) args to pass them to multiple procesess. This means that each process gets a copy of the original list.

To achieve what you want just use the special shared list object from multiprocessing:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
primes = manager.list(range(10))
```

Comment: In fact you **can** allocate objects in shared memory. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes